Why is my webpack bundlerer creating multiple main.js files?
I noticed tree shaking wasn't correctly because I was compiling my TypeScript to 'commonjs'. I changed this to 'ES2015' and now my output build looks like this:
enter image description here.
What's going on here and how do I fix it?
I am only specifying a single entry point so I expect a single output.
I've tried playing about with the tsconfig and looking at stack overflow for solutions but no one else seems to be having this problem.

Please edit your question post to include Typescript and Webpack config files as text. (Screenshots of textual information are typically discouraged on StackOverflow.)

I found the answer. These additional files are called Chunks, I needed to use the LimitChunkCountPlugin to remove them. The solution is:
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
        maxChunks: 1,
    }),
]

